Re-run failed glue job using a step function
I basically want to retry a glue job twice after status FAILED or TIMEOUT, before moving to the next stage. My state machine looks like this:
 {
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Glue StartJobRun",
  "States": {
    "Glue StartJobRun": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "test-to-fail"
      },
      "End": true,
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "MaxAttempts": 2,
          "IntervalSeconds": 300,
          "BackoffRate": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Nevertheless, the job runs one single time when I execute the state machine. Could it be that I misunderstood the logic behind Retry and it applies to the step function state and not the job? I followed this tutorial, which seems to confirm it is the job status. Then, what is wrong? And how can I achieve this?
Thank you!

Is there any reason you don't use the retry functionality within the glue job configuration?

Because an amount of minutes need to pass between retries (can it be configured in the job?). Also, I'm orchestrating other jobs after this one so I was going to use step functions. Perhaps glue workflows could work too

Actually you getting retry logic wrong

"Glue StartJobRun": {   "Type": "Task",   "Resource":
"arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun",

This step will be considered failed if Glue job is not started. And it will retry to start it. As job was started, it is considered success.
Solution:
But to check status of the job you should have next step with retry attempts.

configure if job failed retry

somehow like this..
{
  "Comment": "A state machine that starts a Glue job and checks its status",
  "StartAt": "Start Glue Job",
  "States": {
    "Start Glue Job": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "YourGlueJobName"
      },
      "Next": "Check Job Status"
    },
    "Check Job Status": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:getJobRun",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "YourGlueJobName",
        "RunId.$": "$.RunId"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": ["States.TaskFailed"],
          "IntervalSeconds": 60,
          "MaxAttempts": 2,
          "BackoffRate": 2.0
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}

